# Restart debugging the current function in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When stepping through a Java function using Eclipse, I noticed that saving (a change to) the sources causes Eclipse to restart debugging from the beginning of the function.

Is there a command to restart debugging the current function (or some place higher up in the call stack) without saving first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Lars Vogel's tutorial on [Eclipse Debugging](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and specifically the 'drop to frame' feature. This will give you the feature you want.

Answer (score 4):

To improve SteveD's answer (which is correct all the way), I'll add what I do:

Go to `Preferences` > `General` > `Keys` and search for `Drop to Frame`. Now you can assign a custom shortcut for it under `Binding`. I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> because I see it as the opposite of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (`Run to`) feature.

This immediately jumps to the start of the current method, no mouseclick in the stack required.
You can of course still do that to jump to any frame before the current.

One thing to remember: This is not reverse debugging. It does not reset variables, so if you set static fields or something like that, they will not be reverted to a prior value!